# Relacionar tablas y sumar sus cantidades

Tags: sql-server, phpmyadmin

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, tengo el siguente problema.

tengo 5 tablas en sql server.

1. ingresos, donde se guarda la fecha y las observaciones de los ingresos.
2. detalle_ingresos, aqui se guarda el detalle de los ingresos
3. salidas, donde se guarda la fecha y las observaciones de los ingresos.
4. detalle_ingresos, aqui se guarda el detalle de los ingresos
5. modelos_ventas, donde se muestra el inventario disponible

lo que quiero hacer es una relacion de tablas y desplegar en una sola tabla los siguentes campos.

sku  ingresos  salidas  cantidad disponible

esto por fecha.

el problema es que al ejecutar la consulta solo me despliega los sku donde que han tenido salidas e ingresos, los que no aparecen en las tablas de detalles son otidos.

mi consulta es la siguente.

```sql
SELECT modelos_ventas.modelo, 
       modelos_ventas.sku, 
       SUM(detalle_ingreso.cantidad) as Ingresos, 
       SUM(detalle_pedido.cantidad) AS Salidas,
       modelos_ventas.stock 
FROM modelos_ventas 
   INNER JOIN detalle_ingreso 
      ON modelos_ventas.sku = detalle_ingreso.sku 
   INNER JOIN detalle_pedido 
      ON modelos_ventas.sku = detalle_pedido.sku 
GROUP BY modelos_ventas.sku
```

Comment: eso sucede por el join que estás haciendo, solo mostrará los que tengan ingresos y pedidos (salidas como los llamas), en todo caso para solucionarlo usa el left join y te darán tanto los coincidentes como los no coincidentes; en caso de los que no coincidan (no tengan ingresos ni salidas) entonces tendrás valor nulo en los campos de modelo, sku y stock y dependiendo del registro (ingreso o pedido) tendrás nulo en el campo cantidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono al 100, soy nuevo en esto.

Answer (score 0):

Esta duda es común y genera muchos problemas. Al unir dos tablas con múltiples filas asociadas a una única fila de otra tabla, los datos se duplican y obtienes cantidades más altas de lo que debes. Así que no solo tienes que cambiar el tipo de JOIN para obtener filas de modelos sin ventas o sin compras, también tienes que ajustar para que no duplique las cantidades de las mismas. Para eso hay que hacer la sumatoria antes de unir las tablas.

```
WITH cteSumaIngreso AS(
    SELECT sku,
            SUM(cantidad) AS Ingresos
    FROM detalle_ingreso
    GROUP BY sku
),
cteSumaSalidas AS(
    SELECT sku,
            SUM(cantidad) AS Salidas
    FROM detalle_pedido
    GROUP BY sku
)
SELECT mv.modelo, 
       mv.sku, 
       ISNULL( si.Ingresos, 0) AS Ingresos,
       ISNULL( ss.Salidas,  0) AS Salidas, 
       mv.stock 
FROM      modelos_ventas AS mv
LEFT JOIN cteSumaIngreso AS si ON mv.sku = si.sku 
LEFT JOIN cteSumaSalidas AS ss ON mv.sku = ss.sku
```